# Using PsExec to start Internet Explorer and then navigate to a particular URL

Tags: internet-explorer, psexec

I want to be able to use PsExec to start Internet Explorer, then load a particular website in the browser. I know how to start IE, just can't make a command that goes to a particular webpage. This is what I have so far:

```
psexec "C:\program files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

I just can't figure the syntax for loading anything other than the default start page

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'll usually run something like this:

PsExec.exe \\HOSTNAME -u Administrator -p ******** -i -d -e EXPLORER "http://www.google.com"

`-i` - makes it interactive; so the remote user can see it on their console session.
`-d` - makes psexec not wait for the program to terminate.
`-e` - causes the remote machine to not load the profile of the account we're using to log in with.

Passing the URL to EXPLORER will almost assuredly always work, and it will even open up in the user's default browser. Chrome, Opera, Firefox, IE...

Comment: Should that be a \\ before `computername`?

Comment: Ill recommend this one, parsing through explorer is much more effective than directly opening Internet explorer. For it may failed for such security reason. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you'd want to use PsExec, but it would be like this:

```
psexec "C:\program files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" "http://www.yahoo.com/"
```